# Why doesn't my combobox display text?

Tags: c#, gtk#

I'am working in a GTK-sharp application. I have this code but `combobox1` doesn't display any item. Why not?

```
ListStore store = new ListStore(typeof(myclass));

store.AppendValue(new myclass("hola",7));
store.AppendValue(new myclass("hola2",8));
store.AppendValue(new myclass("hola3",2));

combobox1.Model = store;
```

The class `myclass` overrides `ToString()`

Comment: Why have you not set the following properties for combobox `combobox1.DisplayMember = "description"; combobox1.ValueMember = "id";`?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is custom `Gtk.CellRenderer`:

```
private void MyClassRenderer(CellLayout cell_layout, CellRenderer cell, TreeModel model, TreeIter iter)
{    
    MyClass myclass = model.GetValue(iter, 0) as MyClass;
    (cell as CellRendererText).Text = myclass.ToString();
}
```

With some additional code in the setup method like this:

```
CellRendererText myClassCell = new CellRendererText();
combobox1.PackStart(myClassCell, true);
combobox1.SetCellDataFunc(myClassCell, MyClassRenderer);

ListStore store = new ListStore(typeof(MyClass));

store.AppendValues(new MyClass("hola",7));
store.AppendValues(new MyClass("hola2",8));
store.AppendValues(new MyClass("hola3",2));

combobox1.Model = store;
```

Make sure the `SetCellDataFunc` method is called after `PackStart` method.

Job done! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but make sure the listbox key and values are mapped to the fields in the class. I think it needs to be specific. After setting the value, make sure to do the final databind like: control.DataBind();

In general, C# binding goes like: 1) automatic colum generation/manually map all fields to keys and values 2). set the field 3. and call the bind() function.